# How to Sum Columns From Two Result Sets in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have the following table:

ratings:

```
ID | post_id | rating_type
```

The rating_type field is either 'thumb-up' or 'thumb-down'.  I want to get a result set telling me what the highest rated posts are.  The following query gives me a result set with the number of up votes for each unique post_id.

```
SELECT COUNT(post_id) as number_up, post_id FROM wp_sp_post_ratings WHERE rating_type = 'thumb-up' GROUP BY post_id
```

That is great!  I can do similarly for the thumb-down rating type.  However, what I need is to get the total rating where each thumb-up gives a post one point and each thumb down gives a post a negative point.  Then, I need to order that by the total amount of rating.  So, say we have the following:

post 1 has 3 up votes and 2 down votes
post 2 has 14 up votes and 33 down votes
post 3 has 4 up votes and 0 down votes

I'd like to see a result set like the following:

```
post_id | total_rating
3 | 4
1 | 1
2 | -19
```

I have no idea how to do this.  I've been banging my head against the documentation and Google for about 2 hours now, so I was hoping that SO could be my savior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN rating_type = 'up' THEN 1 WHEN rating_type = 'down' THEN -1 END CASE)
FROM posts
GROUP BY post_id
```

P. S. It's better to keep up and down votes as numbers (+1 and -1) rather than strings.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, why not store a thumbs up as 1 and a thumbs down as -1 directly? Quassnoi was quicker with the case statement....

Comment: I would have preferred to do that, but the spec called for possible extensibility to a star rating system but not to take too much time.  One of those vague requirements where you make compromises, you know?